# How to find and replace a string with newline in emeditor

Tags: text, edit, emeditor

I have the data in the following format;

```
(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief p','xxxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief Pollster','xxxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief Pollster','xxxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief Pollster','xxxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief p','xxxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),
(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief Pollster','xxcxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),
(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief Pollster','xxxxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),
(1,NULL,NULL,'Chief Pollster','xxsxx@email.com','new',4,'1ef7,0,2),
```

So I tried the following regex

find `),\s*` and replace it with `),\n`

But it says

> The regex contains mismatched '(' and ')'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `)` is a special char, it ust be escaped in the regex pattern.

Comment: I found this to be working:

Searched `)` and replace it with `/n` while I selected "Escape sequence"